# Resolving ES6 import path with fallback in Webpack 2

Tags: webpack

My folders' structure is as follows:

```
- test
  - scripts
      index.js
      user.js
- default
  - scripts
      index.js
      api.js
      user.js
```

I need to resolve an import path locally ("test" directory), while the fallback in case of failure should be resolved through the "default" directory.

The code in test/scripts/index.js is:

```
import api from 'scripts/api'; // should be taken from 'default'
import user from 'scripts/user; // should take the local 'user.js'
...
```

I'm using Webpack 2.1.0 with the following configuration:

```
...
resolve: {
    modules: [
        path.resolve( './default' )
    ]
}
...
```

This configuration makes webpack to resolve all the module `'script/*'` paths through 'default', while relative `'./script/*'` paths never gets out of the module's directory, so no relative path can be used as a fallback.

It seems like `resolve.fallback` is not supported by Webpack 2

I've tried to write a plugin to `normal-module-factory->before-resolve`, but the only paths I receive are the entry paths.

Is there any possible configuration to solve that?
Is writing a custom loader could be the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Can [`resolve.modulesDirectories`](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-modulesdirectories) help?

Comment: @CD.. I'm afraid not. I'm not looking for an ancestor, but for a sibling on a certain level. Besides, it is told webpack 2 configuration of resolve differs from the 1.x one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this

```
resolve: {
  modules: [
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/source-folder'),
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/fallback-folder'),
    'node_modules',
  ]
}
```

or try this plugin:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-fallback-directory-resolver-plugin